# New to lme4 in R - am I modeling this correctly?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

**Experiment**: Given mice of two genetic backgrounds (normal, mutant), is there a difference in brain inflammation as determined by fluorescence intensity of an inflammatory marker?

**Data**: 19 mice (12 in genotype = normal, 7 in genotype = mutant) across 90 observations (3-7 observations per mouse) were analyzed.

**Model (code in R)**:

```
model = lme(inflammation ~ genotype + (1|mouse))
```

inflammation = continuous dependent variable

genotype = categorical independent variable (binary), fixed effects

mouse = arbitrary number, random effects

Does this sound right to you?

Comment: Have you factored the data frame?

Comment: @noumenal what do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry for the lingo. For nominal variables it is good practice to update the data frame with `as.factor`: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html Also applies to ordinal vars, but see docs.

Comment: @noumenal the question is about specifying a model, not how to code variables, but I agree with your advice about checking codings, as a general matter.

Comment: It was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the as.factor - actually this is very helpful, because I have other experiments that I was hoping to analyze that have more than 2 nominal variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a good model for your data and your research question.

However, note that the syntax your wrote is for `lmer` from the `lme4` package, not `lme` from the `nlme` package. `lme4` is more recent is preferred to `nlme` unless you want to model covariance structures.

The model will estimate the fixed effect of `genotype` while controlling for the random effect of each mouse (since measurements on the same mouse may be more alike one another than those on a different mouse).

Comment: Thank you both! Re: gung - I'm not sure what you mean by this. Re: Robert long - thank you for sharing this! Yes, I think I mistyped the syntax and meant "lmer" as I used the library "lme4"

Comment: @Robert, I have edited the the title.  gung simply made some edits to your OP. Maybe you are talking about the comment from noumenal ? I don't know what that means either. If you think I have answered your question, you can "accept" it.

Comment: Oh - sorry about that, I'm quite new to using the interface of stackexchange, and see why this comment is misplaced.